# Invalid identifier error while using File upload server side controller in c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error while using `Fileupload` controller in c# asp.net.

> Error: Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
>    Parser Error Message: 'txtExpCert" + i + "' is not a valid identifier.

    Source Error: 


    Line 567:             }
    Line 568:             $.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
    Line 569:             $('#expOl').append("<li><div class='totalaligndiv'>
<div class='col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1'>
<asp:FileUpload  runat='server' CssClass='filestyle' data-size='lg' 
name='expcerti' id='txtExpCert" + i + "' ></div>
<div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm ' id='Expadd'>+</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='minus'
style='display:none'>-</button></div>
<div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
    Line 570:             //$('.filestyle').attr("id","expcerti"+i);
    Line 571:             $(this).css('display', 'none');

    Source File: /DoctorSignUp.aspx    Line: 569
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
             $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function () {
                  var i;
                 if (sessionStorage.length == 0) {
                      i = 1;
                 } else {
                      i = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
                 }
                 $.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
                 $('#expOl').append("<li><div class='totalaligndiv'>
<div class='col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1'>
<asp:FileUpload  runat='server' CssClass='filestyle' data-size='lg' 
name='expcerti' id='txtExpCert" + i + "' ></div>
<div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm ' id='Expadd'>
+</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='minus' 
style='display:none'>-</button></div>
<div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
                 //$('.filestyle').attr("id","expcerti"+i);
                 $(this).css('display', 'none');
                 $(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
                 i++;
                 sessionStorage.setItem('id', i);
             });
             $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
                 console.log('delete');
                 $(this).closest("li").remove();
             });
         });
```

Actually when i am putting simple file input(`i.e-<input type='file' class='filestyle' data-size='lg' name='expcerti' id='txtExpCert"+i+"' >`) its working properly but here my requirement is to generate generate server side file controller using asp.net.Please help me to resolve this error.Suppose file inputs are generate properly as you can check i am generating id dynamically for each input so how can i access those file values in backend code file using c#.Please help me.

Comment: `i` is declared in the wrong scope.

Comment: @ Tieson : Can you make this correct ?

Comment: No, but *you* can. Declare it outside of the if/else statement, then set it appropriately.

Comment: No,same error is coming after changing.I changed as per you.You can check my post again.Here two build errors also there `i.e-Too many charcters in character literal and ; expected`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax earlier in the page.

Comment: But when i am adding simple input type file no error is coming..

Comment: Well, using JavaScript to insert a server tag will not work. Those are rendered server-side, so you're inserting invalid markup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84339/discussion-between-satya-and-tieson-t).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
<asp:FileUpload  runat='server' CssClass='filestyle' data-size='lg' 
name='expcerti' id='txtExpCert" + i + "' >
```

add controls dynamically rather than naming it dynamically like below code,

```
FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
fu.ID = "fu1";
form1.Controls.Add(fu);
```

Comment: @ Karthik: After adding your line it gave another error `The server tag is not well formed.` I added this line `<asp:FileUpload  runat="server" CssClass="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="txtExpCert" +i ></asp:FileUpload>`

Comment: @satya Actually what you are trying to achieve by dynamically naming the control? 
Is it possible for you to achieve the goal by generating dynamic controls not only the name?

Comment: @ Karthik :Actually i have one file input filed with one add button.My requirement is when user will click on that add button one new input type file field will create.I am also confused.Give me some solution .

Comment: @satya go to the code behind of button click event, then add one control dynamically.

Comment: @ Karthik : Can you help me to write the code as per you so that it will be like what ever jquery click event contains.